I got an error when switching from Angular 17 to version 18
I was trying to update a project from Angular 14 to 18.
Of course I did it gradually from 14 to 15.
Then from 15 to 16, then from 16 to 17 and currently from 17 to 18
When updating from 16 to 17 I got this error
Error: node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effect_creator.d.ts:42:101 - error TS2313: Type parameter 'OT' has a circular constraint.

42 export declare function createEffect<C extends EffectConfig, DT extends DispatchType<C>, OT extends ObservableType<DT, OT>, R extends EffectResult<OT>>(source: () => R & ConditionallyDisallowActionCr
eator<DT, R>, config?: Partial<C>): R & CreateEffectMetadata;

I searched and found that the Typescript version 5.3.3 needs to be installed to fix this error.
I fixed this error for version 17 of Angular and everything worked fine
When switching to Angular 18, the error repeated
But there is one problem for Angular 18 you need to have a Typescript version >=5.4.0 <5.5.0.
I would be glad if someone could help me, thanks in advance
I tried installing different versions of Typescript but could not fix the error

try removing .angular folder, node_modules and package-lock.json, then do a install and start

Before I wrote here, I already tried everything, but I couldn’t solve the problem

could you try installing the latest version of ngrx, or try downgrading typescript

Have you tried to update to the Angular v18 compatible Typescript version? (latest 5.4.x?)

Yes I did it too
